# biblatex ignores useeditor=false option

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm trying to remove the editor from the bibliography by setting `useeditor=false`. However, this option seems to have no effect, neither when set globally, nor per entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INBOOK{key4,
  AUTHOR          = {Author},
  TITLE           = {Orig Language Title},
  BOOKTITLE       = {Booktitle},
  LOCATION        = {Location},
  PUBLISHER       = {Publisher2},
  DATE            = {2011-22},
  PAGES           = {33--57}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{Chunyuan2017,
  author = {Li, Chunyuan and Liu, Hao and Chen, Changyou and Pu, Yuchen and Chen, Liqun and Henao, Ricardo and Carin, Lawrence},
  booktitle = {Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 30},
  editor = {Guyon, I and Luxburg, U V and Bengio, S and Wallach, H and Fergus, R and Vishwanathan, S and Garnett, R},
  pages = {5495--5503},
  publisher = {Curran Associates, Inc.},
  title = {{ALICE: Towards Understanding Adversarial Learning for Joint Distribution Matching}},
  year = {2017}
}
@ARTICLE{Botta2014,
  author = {Botta, Vincent and Louppe, Gilles and Geurts, Pierre and Wehenkel, Louis},
  title = {{Exploiting SNP Correlations within Random Forest for Genome-Wide Association Studies}},
  doi = {10.1371/journal.pone.0093379},
  editor = {Chen, Lin},
  issn = {1932-6203},
  journal = {PLoS ONE},
  month = APR,
  number = {4},
  pages = {e93379},
  volume = {9},
  year = {2014}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{useeditor=false}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I tried with biber 2.11 and biblatex 3.11 as well as the latest version
(biber 2.14 and biblatex 3.14). Both give the same result:

[image: generated PDF]

I've also tried `useauthor=false`, which works.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useeditor=false` does not remove the `editor` from the bibliography. If it takes effect at all, it just moves it around a bit and prevents the `editor` from taking the `author` position for sorting and label generation

The documentation explains the option as follows

> [`useeditor`] Whether the `editor` replaces a missing `author` in labels and during sorting.
>   This may be useful if an entry includes an `editor` field but is usually not cited by editor.
>   Setting `useeditor=false` does not mean that the editor is ignored completely.
>   It means that the `editor` does not replace a missing `author` in labels and during
>   sorting.
>   The entry will then be alphabetized by `title`.
>   With the standard styles, the editor is printed after the title in this case.

You can see the effect of `useeditor` in the following example

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@mvcollection{britannica:simplified,
  editor       = {Preece, Warren E.},
  title        = {The {New Encyclop{\ae}dia Britannica}},
  date         = {2003},
  edition      = 15,
  volumes      = 32,
  publisher    = {Encyclop{\ae}dia Britannica},
  location     = {Chicago, Ill.},
  options      = {useeditor=false},
  label        = {EB},
  sorttitle    = {Encyclop{\ae}dia Britannica},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{britannica:simplified}
\nocite{cicero,nussbaum,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With `useeditor=false` `britannica:simplified` is cited as

> EB 2003

and sorted under "E" (due to `sorttitle = {Encyclop{\ae}dia Britannica},`) because the `editor` does not replace the missing `author` field (so `label` is used as a fallback).

But with `useeditor=true` the citation is

> Preece 2003

and the work is sorted under "P".

---

If you want to remove the editor, that is best done via a Biber sourcemap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=editor, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@INBOOK{key4,
  AUTHOR     = {Author},
  TITLE      = {Orig Language Title},
  BOOKTITLE  = {Booktitle},
  LOCATION   = {Location},
  PUBLISHER  = {Publisher2},
  DATE       = {2011-22},
  PAGES      = {33--57}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{Chunyuan2017,
  author    = {Li, Chunyuan and Liu, Hao and Chen, Changyou
               and Pu, Yuchen and Chen, Liqun and Henao, Ricardo
               and Carin, Lawrence},
  booktitle = {Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 30},
  editor    = {Guyon, I. and Luxburg, U. V. and Bengio, S.
               and Wallach, H. and Fergus, R. and Vishwanathan, S.
               and Garnett, R.},
  pages     = {5495--5503},
  publisher = {Curran Associates, Inc.},
  title     = {{ALICE}: Towards Understanding Adversarial Learning for Joint Distribution Matching},
  year      = {2017},
}
@ARTICLE{Botta2014,
  author  = {Botta, Vincent and Louppe, Gilles and Geurts, Pierre and Wehenkel, Louis},
  title   = {Exploiting {SNP} Correlations within Random Forest for Genome-Wide Association Studies},
  doi     = {10.1371/journal.pone.0093379},
  editor  = {Chen, Lin},
  issn    = {1932-6203},
  journal = {PLoS ONE},
  month   = APR,
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {e93379},
  volume  = {9},
  year    = {2014}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{useeditor=false}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\DeclareSourcemap` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot.